# Point Connection String to custom utility

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-config, database-connection, connection-string

Currently we have our Asp mvc LOB web application talking to an SQL server database. This is setup through the a connection string in the web.config as usual.

We are having performance issues with some of our bigger customers that are running some really large reports and kpi's on the database which choke it up and cause performance issues for the rest of the users.

Our solution so far is to setup replication on the database and pass all the report and kpi data calls off to the replicated server and leave the main server for the common critical use.

Without having add another connection string to the config for the replicated server and go through the application and direct the report, kpi and other read only calls to the secondary db is there a way I can point the web.config connection string to an intermediary node that will analyse the data request and shuffle it off to the appropriate db accordingly? i.e. If the data call is a standard update process on the db it will shuffle that to the main db and if there is a report being loaded it will pass it off to the secondary replicated server.

We will only need to add this node in for the bigger customers with larger db's, so if we can get away with adding a node outside the current application setup it will save us a lot of code changes and testing needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just curious, what is your hesitation with using multiple connection strings? If you did this, then your app code could make the determination on which server to query. This makes sense to me since your app would know best, but I'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your response trnelson. This is an option but I want to see if we could intersect at the connection string level first. Being the fact the bulk of our customers dont have this problem (only about 5% do, but they are the bigger ones that pay the bills) if I can slip this in outside the application it will mean that we dont have to move much around in the app that has already been tested and stable. I think it would be a lot more elastic being the custom utility could just be changed to say, ok queries for this data set should now be passed to the secondary, not go thru and change all

Comment: It appears that a feature similar to a load balancer would help here, but AFAIK SQL Server doesn't come with one built-in. One possibility is to focus the reporting data source to views. Views then can be on another server, and you may even consider creating distributed partitioned views. If you can use schema, you can even create a view in db B/schema X to target db B/schema dbo, and then instead of SELECT FROM dbo.Table1 user writes SELECT FROM X.Table1

Comment: You should change your app. SQL Server NLB is tricky. If you can't modify your app, you should probably use sql server clustering instead of replication in that case... and this is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Hi rivarolle, Thanks for the response. Why would we need to go down clustering. Having a two tier replication setup is easy to setup and manage. Just need to than direct the calls correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it may be easier for you to add a second connection string for reports, etc. instead of trying to analyse the request.

The reasons are as follows:

1. You probably have a fairly good idea which areas of your system need to go the second database. Once you identify them, you can just point them to to the second database and not worry about switching them back and forth.
2. You can just create 2 connection string in you config file. If you have only one database for smaller customers, you can point both connections to the same one database. For bigger customers, you can use two different connection strings. This way you will make the system flexible and configurable.
3. Analysing requests usually turns out to be complex and adding this additional complexity seems unwarranted in this case.

All my comments are based on what you wrote above and may not be absolutely valid - you know they system better, just use them if you want.